# Postgres Free Space Map (FSM) file errors

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have been having a larger number of the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  could not open file "base/16420/2436243_fsm": Invalid argument
```

It seems to be a result of some large postGIS process.  Is there anything I should look into to reduce this type of an error?

I have run vacuum on all of the tables and opened up more space.

Comment: What version of postgresql are you using? You could get a better error message by setting "log_error_verbosity = verbose"

Answer (score 0):

backup and restore.  This sounds like a corrupted freespace map.  There's not much room above your db to resolve this.

To cut down on errors:

1. Check and recheck hardware (RAM, CPU, hard drives).  This means diagnostics and manual checks.  Make sure using ECC RAM and the like.
2. Make sure you are up to date within the stable branch of PostgreSQL